# How to get max value at the same index in array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like this:

```
data = [
   [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39}, {a: "bb",  value: 150}],
   [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83}, {a: "ccc", value: 12}],
   [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value: 9},  {a: "dd",  value: 1}]
]
```

I want to get the largest value at the same index in this data, so I want the result to be like this:

```
[55, 83, 150]
```

Right now, I can get each value in objects, and I can get the largest value if I specify the index. I am not sure how to do it with every index.

```
let array = [];
data.map((eachArr, index) => {
   array.push(eachArr[0].value)

   for(let i = 0; i < eachArr.length; i++){
     console.log('eachArr[i].value', eachArr[i].value, i);
   }
})
console.log(Math.max(...array)) ===> 55
```

How can I do this?

I think people misunderstood my question. I do not want the largest value from each array. I want the largest value of `value` with the same index in every array. So I want 55 from 12, 15, 55, 83 from 39, 83, 9, and 150 from 150, 12, 1. I am sorry for not being specific. I should have an example with different length.

Comment: Thats not an array of arrays, thats an array of object literals.

Comment: @max Actually, it **is** an array of arrays (of objects).

Comment: @torazaburo I think people misunderstood my question. I do not want the largest value from each array. I want the largest value of  `value` with the same index in every array. So I want `55` from `12, 15, 55`, `83` from `39, 83, 9`, and `150` from `150, 12, 1`. I am sorry for not being specific. I should have an example with different length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```js
var data = [[{ a: "b",value: 12}, { a: "bb",value: 39 }, { a: "bb", value: 150 }], [{   a: "c",   value: 15 }, {   a: "cc",   value: 83 }, {   a: "ccc",   value: 12 }], [{   a: "d",  value: 55 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 9 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 1 }]];


console.log(
  // iterate over the array
  data.reduce(function(arr, ele) {
    // iterate over the inner array
    ele.forEach(function(o, i) {
      // check element present at the index, if not then update with current value
      arr[i] = arr[i] || o.value;
      // check assign greatest value by comparing with previous value
      arr[i] = arr[i] < o.value ? o.value : arr[i];
      
      // you can combine above two lines
      // arr[i] = !arr[i] || arr[i] < o.value ? o.value : arr[i];
      
    });
    // return the array reference
    return arr;
    // set initial value as an empty array
  }, [])
)


// without any comments
console.log(
  data.reduce(function(arr, ele) {
    ele.forEach(function(o, i) {
      arr[i] = !arr[i] || arr[i] < o.value ? o.value : arr[i];
    });
    return arr;
  }, [])
)
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```js
let data = [[{ a: "b",value: 12}, { a: "bb",value: 39 }, { a: "bb", value: 150 }], [{   a: "c",   value: 15 }, {   a: "cc",   value: 83 }, {   a: "ccc",   value: 12 }], [{   a: "d",  value: 55 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 9 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 1 }]];

console.log(
  data.reduce((arr, ele) => (ele.forEach((o, i) => arr[i] = !arr[i] || arr[i] < o.value ? o.value : arr[i]), arr), [])
)
```

---

Using the simple for loop with the same logic.

```js
var data = [[{ a: "b",value: 12}, { a: "bb",value: 39 }, { a: "bb", value: 150 }], [{   a: "c",   value: 15 }, {   a: "cc",   value: 83 }, {   a: "ccc",   value: 12 }], [{   a: "d",  value: 55 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 9 }, {   a: "dd",   value: 1 }]];

var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    res[j] = !res[j] || res[j] < data[i][j].value ? data[i][j].value : res[j];
  }
} 

console.log(res);
```

---

**FYI :** [Performance comparison](https://jsperf.com/compare-two-functions)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
// Get the maxes from rows
 data.map(function(a){
    return Math.max.apply( null, a.map(function(b){ return b.value; }) );
 });

// Get maxes from cols
var maxes = data.map(function(v,i){
    return Math.max.apply( null, data.map(function(a){
       return a[i].value;
    }));
});
console.log("Maxes: ",maxes);
// Maxes:  [ 55, 83, 150 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```js
const data = [
   [{a: "b", value: 12}, {a: "bb", value: 39}, {a: "bb", value: 11}], 
   [{a: "c", value: 15}, {a: "cc", value: 83}, {a: "cc", value: 12}], 
   [{a: "d", value: 55}, {a: "dd", value:  9}, {a: "dd", value:  1}]
];    

const result = data[0].map((_, i) => 
  Math.max(...data.map(subarray => subarray[i].value)));

console.log(result);
```

Note that this will not work properly if the subarrays are not of the same length.

If you prefer an ES5 version:

```
const result = data[0].map(function(_, i) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function(subarray) {
    return subarray[i].value;
  }));
});
```